# Complete induction:figure out the last step

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to solve this task on complete induction. I am sorry for the form, if you see a   $6$
it means: a divisible through six. Could anyone please check if I have done right? Because at the end, I don´t know how to show that  4n³+2n²+3n is divisible through six.

Please show by complete induction, that  for every $n\in\mathbb N$:  $(n²)² -n³ -n²+n$ is divisible through $6$

1) $\frac{(1²)²-1³ -1²+1 }{6}=\frac06= 0$   true statement

2) inductive hypothesis:

$\frac{(n²)²-n³-n²+n }{6}$

3) inductive step:
$n\gt n+1$

$$\frac{((n+1)²)²-(n+1)³-(n+1)²+(n+1)}{6}=$$

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1)(n+1)(n+1)-(n+1)(n+1)(n+1)-(n+1)(n+1)+(n+1)}{6}=$$

$$\frac{(n²+2n+1)(n²+2n+1)–(n²+2n+1)(n+1)-(n²+2n+1)+(n+1)}{6}=$$

$$\frac{(n²)²+ 2n³+n² +2n³+4n²+2n+1–(n²+2n+1)(n+1)-(n²+2n+1)+(n+1)}{6}=$$

$$\frac{(n²)²+4n³+5n²+2n+1-(n³+n²+2n²+2n+n+1)-(n²+2n+1)+(n+1)}{ 6}=$$

$$4(n²)²-n³-n²-2n$$
=inductive
hypothesis

$+ 4n³+2n²+3n $ ??? (divisible through six?)

Comment: ohhh sorry. I will have my exam on thursday and afterwards I hope I dont need to ask more questions here... This is why I didnt make the effort to get to know latex.. Very sorry! hope you can still read it??

Comment: I just realized, thanks to Math Gems, that you made a mistake in your calculation, so my answer doesn’t really apply to the question. It’s still useful as a demonstration of technique, but you should take a look at the revised version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your approach isn’t the easiest one. However, it **is** possible to finish your argument. Your induction hypothesis is that

$$6\mid(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2+n\;,$$

and at the end you need to show that

$$6\mid 4(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2-2n\tag{1}$$

to complete the induction step. (In case you haven’t seen it before, the notation $a\mid b$ means that $a$ is a divisor of $b$.)

You know that $(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2+n=6k$ for some integer $k$. Multiply that equation by $4$, so that the first term matches the $4(n^2)^2$ in $(1)$:

$$4(n^2)^2-4n^3-4n^2+4n=24k\;.$$

Now how much does your $4(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2-2n$ differ from this quantity?

$$\left(4(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2-2n\right)-\left(4(n^2)^2-4n^3-4n^2+4n\right)=3n^3+3n^2-6n\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\left(4(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2-2n\right)&=\left(4(n^2)^2-4n^3-4n^2+4n\right)+3n^3+3n^2-6n\\
&=24k+3n^3+3n^2-6n\\
&=6(4k-n)+3n^2(n+1)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $6(4k-n)$ is certainly a multiple of $6$, so we’ll be done if we can show that $3n^2(n+1)$ is a multiple of $6$. But that’s easy: it’s obviously a multiple of $3$, and one of the consecutive integers $n$ and $n+1$ must be even, so $3n^2(n+1)$ must be an even multiple of $3$, i.e., a multiple of $6$. Thus, $6(4k-n)$ and $3n^2(n+1)$ are both multiples of $6$, and the sum of two multiples of $6$ is a multiple of $6$, so $(1)$ is true, and the induction step is complete.

**Added:** Unfortunately, the polynomial $(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2-2n$ is incorrect, because you made some algebra errors: $\big((n+1)^2\big)^2-(n+1)^3-(n+1)^2+(n+1)$ actually simplifies to $n^4+3n^3+2n^2$. But we can use the same idea: by how much does this differ from

$$(n^2)^2-n^3-n^2+n\;,$$

the known multiple of $6$?

$$\Big(n^4+3n^3+2n^2\Big)-\Big((n^2)^2-n^3-n^2+n\Big)=4n^3+3n^2-n\;,$$

so we’re done if we can show that $4n^3+3n^2-n$ is a multiple of $6$. Now

$$4n^3+3n^2-n=n\left(4n^2+3n-1\right)=n(n+1)(4n-1)\;,$$

and the product $n(n+1)$ of two consecutive numbers is certainly even, so we need only show that $n(n+1)(4n-1)$ is also a multiple of $3$. The integer $n$ must be of the form $3k$, $3k+1$, or $3k+2$. If $n=3k$ for some $k$, then $n$ itself is a multiple of $3$, and so is $n(n+1)(4n-1)$. If $n=3k+2$ for some $k$, then $n+1=3k+3$ is a multiple of $3$, and so is $n(n+1)(4n-1)$. And if $n=3k+1$ for some $k$, then $4n-1=12k+3=3(4k+1)$ is a multiple of $3$, and so is $n(n+1)(4n-1)$. In every case, therefore, $n(n+1)(4n-1)$ is an even multiple of $3$ and hence a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: @Sophia: You’re welcome!

Comment: Where does the polynomial in $(1)$ come from?

Comment: @MathGems: Sophia’s calculation, which I took on faith. Unfortunately, her calculation appears to be wrong, so I’m going to have to go back and take a closer look. (My calculation is still somewhat useful, however, as an example of the sort of manipulation that one might need to make.)

Comment: @Brian In your edit you show *directly* that $6\mid f(n\!+\!1),\,$ but if you read the question closely you'll notice the OP correctly starts developing the requested *inductive* proof of the form $\, 6\mid f(n)\Rightarrow 6\mid f(n\!+\!1),\:$ but then, at the end, instead of doing the inductive step, the OP apparently tries to finish with a direct (non-inductive) proof. So it appears that the OP's errors lie not only in calculations.

Comment: @MathGems: Argh. You’re right; I got distracted and lost track of what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ f(n)\, =\, (n\!-\!1)^2n(n\!+\!1)\:$ has as factor a product of $3$ consecutive integers, one of which is divisible by $2$, and one divisible by $3\,$ (this can be proved by induction if that way is required).

Alternatively, $\rm\displaystyle\ \ \frac{f(n)}6\, =\, \frac{(n\!-\!1)^2n(n\!+\!1)}6\, =\, (n\!-\!1){n\!+\!1\choose 3}\,\in\,\Bbb Z$

Or, $\rm\,\ f(n) = (n\!-\!1)(n^3\!-\!n),\:$ and $\rm\ n^3\!\equiv n\,\ mod\,\ 3,\,2\ $ by little Fermat.

**Remark** $\ $ If you fix the errors in your calculations you'll end trying to prove as your inductive step that $\rm\ 6\mid f(n\!+\!1)\!-\!f(n) = 4n^3\!+3n^2\!-n = (4n\!-\!1)n(n\!+\!1) = (n\!-\!1)n(n\!+\!1) + 3n^2(n\!+\!1).\:$ This can be done as above, since $\,2\,$ divides one of $\rm\,n,\,n\!+\!1,\:$ and $\rm\,3\,$ divides one of $\rm\:n\!-\!1,\,n,\,n\!+\!1.\:$

Calculating the first difference $\rm\:f(n\!+\!1)-f(n)\:$ is easy using the *factored* form of $\rm\,f,\,$ viz.

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm f(n\!+\!1)-f(n) &\,=\,&\rm n^2(n\!+\!1)(n\!+\!2)-(n\!-\!1)^2n(n\!+\!1)\\  &=&\rm n(n\!+\!1)\,(n(n\!+\!2)-(n\!-\!1)^2)\\ &=&\rm n(n\!+\!1)(4n\!-\!1)\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: but how did you get this out of 4n³+2n²+3n  ??

Comment: @Sophia Above $\rm\:f(n) = n^4\! - n^3\! -n^2\! + n\:$ is the original polynomial. It's a simpler way to prove it.

Comment: okay thank you for this different idea!

Comment: @Sophia I added a remark showing how to complete your approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use induction, you are looking to assume $n^4-n^3-n^2+n$ is a multiple of $6$ and prove $(n+1)^4-(n+1)^3-(n+1)^2+n$ is.  So $$((n+1)^4-(n+1)^3-(n+1)^2+n+1)-(n^4-n^3-n^2+n)=4(n+1)^3+6(n+1)^2+4(n+1)+1-3(n+1)^2-3(n+1)-1-2(n+1)-1+1=4n^3+3n^2-n+=n(n+1)(4n-1)$$
One of the first two terms is even and one of the three is a multiple of $3$, so the difference $f(n+1)-f(n)$ is divisible by $6$

Comment: Oki Thank you for help!!

Comment: The calculation looks wrong. It seems you have $\rm\:g(n) = f(n\!+\!1)-f(n)\:$ on the left, but  $\rm\:g(n\!+\!1)\:$ on the right.

Comment: @MathGems: Where is that?  For example, after the first =, the first four terms come from $(n+1)^4-n^4$, the next three from the cube term, and so on.  g(n+1) has a quartic term, but none of the expressions (after the first) do.

Comment: See my answer for an easy calculation of $\rm\:f(n\!+\!1)-f(n) = n(n\!+\!1)(4n\!-\!1).\:$ The above seems to have a spurious shift $\rm\:n\to n\!+\!1\:$ in the result.

Comment: @MathGems:  found and fixed.  Thanks.  You are correct your approach is slicker.